# ITextsharp PDFParser extracting text to textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to extract file from PDF to a textbox in asp.net, and I have tried this code from the [project here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET)

I have successfully extract the text from my PDF, but the result is exported to .txt file first, and the result doesn't have any line, and there aren't any whitespace between words.

If this is the example of the PDF text

```
Hello World
This is the word ----------------------------------------------- This is word too
End of Hello World
```

The result will be like this

> HelloWorld Thisistheword Thisiswordtoo EndofHelloWorld

What should I do so I can have a space between every word, and add new line in every line?

Also in this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET I saw the following code:

```
int totalLen = 68;
float charUnit = ((float)totalLen) / (float)reader.NumberOfPages;
int totalWritten = 0;
float curUnit = 0;
```

What's the use of it?

**Edit:**
After searching for some more, I found the solution in the [comment here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET?msg=4146288#xx4146288xx)
I just need to update my itextsharp.dll to the newer version ( I use version 5.4.4.0 ) and added the function like what the comment says and now the result is good like what I wanted it to be

Comment: Great you found it. The project you initially found employs a very naive approach to text extraction. iTextSharp's own implementation is way more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some sort of Trim() function happening in the PDFParser.
In addition to that,in the ExtractTextFromPDFBytes method, the newline tokens it is checking is incorrect, it should not be 'TD', 'Td':
Check for iTextSharp.text.Chunk.NEWLINE

Comment: Thanks for the answer, found the solution already a little bit before you post your answer.

what I need to do is just update my itextsharp.dll to the newer version and use the new function like in the comment here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14170/Extract-Text-from-PDF-in-C-100-NET?msg=4146288#xx4146288xx